# How to create JSON array within a JSON array

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, perl

3 tables in MYSQL

```
table_product - product_id, product_name
table_variane - variant_id, variant_name
table_product_variants - product_id,  variant_id, MRP, SellPrice
```

I want to create JSON data out of those in Perl for all the products, in this format:

```
[
    {
        "ProductID": "1",
        "ProductName": "Green Detergent Bar",
        "Variants": [
            {
                "VariantID": "1",
                "VariantName": "500GM",
                "MRP": "20.00",
                "SellPrice": "19.50"
            },
            {
                "VariantID": "2",
                "VariantName": "1KG",
                "MRP": "40.00",
                "SellPrice": "38.00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ProductID": "2",
        "ProductName": "ABCD",
        "Variants": [
            {
                "VariantID": "3",
                "VariantName": "1KG",
                "MRP": "200.00",
                "SellPrice": "190.50"
            },
            {
                "VariantID": "2",
                "VariantName": "1KG",
                "MRP": "40.00",
                "SellPrice": "38.00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is Perl Code

```
my $sql_query = "";     //need to fill this.
my $statement = $db_handle->prepare ($sql_query) or die "Couldn't prepare query '$sql_query': $DBI::errstr\n";  
$statement->execute() or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";  

my @loop_data = ();

while (my @data = $statement->fetchrow_array())
{
    my %data =  //need to fill this too.

    push(@loop_data, \%data);
}

my $json_text = to_json(\@loop_data);
print $json_text;
```

Please help in filling SQL query and while loop.

Its just a blueprint. Any modification in code is also fine.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Can you please explain what part of the SQL query you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That you need arrays (not hashes) complicates things a bit.

### Option 1

Use two queries, one that finds the products, and one that finds the variants of a product.

```
my $product_sth = $dbh->prepare("
   SELECT product_id,
          product_name
     FROM table_product
");

my $variant_sth = $dbh->prepare("
   SELECT tv.variant_id,
          tv.variant_name,
          tvp.MRP,
          tvp.SellPrice
     FROM table_product_variants AS tpv
     JOIN table_variant AS tv
       ON tpv.variant_id = tv.variant_id
    WHERE tpv.product_id = ?
");
```

```
my @data;
while (my $product_row = $product_sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
   my @variants;
   $variant_sth->execute($product_row->{product_id});
   while (my $variant_row = $variant_sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
      push @variants, {
         VariantID   => $variant_row->{variant_id},
         VariantName => $variant_row->{variant_name},
         MRP         => $variant_row->{MRP},
         SellPrice   => $variant_row->{SellPrice},
      };
   }

   push @data, {
      ProductID   => $product_row->{product_id},
      ProductName => $product_row->{product_name},
      Variants    => \@variants,
   };
}

my $data_json = to_json(\@data);
```

### Option 2

Use an HoA to group the variants of a product when using a single query.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("
   SELECT tp.product_id,
          tp.product_name,
          tv.variant_id,
          tv.variant_name,
          tvp.MRP,
          tvp.SellPrice
     FROM table_product AS tp
     JOIN table_product_variants AS tpv
       ON tp.product_id = tpv.product_id
     JOIN table_variant AS tv
       ON tpv.variant_id = tv.variant_id
");
```

```
my %data;
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
   my $product_id = $row->{product_id};

   my $product = $data{$product_id} ||= {
      ProductID   => $row->{product_id},
      ProductName => $row->{product_name},
      Variants    => [],
   };

   push @{ $product->{Variants} }, {
      VariantID   => $row->{variant_id},
      VariantName => $row->{variant_name},
      MRP         => $row->{MRP},
      SellPrice   => $row->{SellPrice},
   };
}

my $data_json = to_json([ values(%data) ]);
```

### Option 3

Use sorting to group the variants of a product when using a single query.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("
   SELECT tp.product_id,
          tp.product_name,
          tv.variant_id,
          tv.variant_name,
          tvp.MRP,
          tvp.SellPrice
     FROM table_product AS tp
     JOIN table_product_variants AS tpv
       ON tp.product_id = tpv.product_id
     JOIN table_variant AS tv
       ON tpv.variant_id = tv.variant_id
    ORDER BY tp.product_id
");
```

```
my $last_product_id = 0;
my @data;
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
   my $product_id = $row->{product_id};

   if ($product_id != $last_product_id) {
      $last_product_id = $product_id;
      push @data, {
         ProductID   => $row->{product_id},
         ProductName => $row->{product_name},
         Variants    => [],
      };
   }

   push @{ $data[-1]{Variants} }, {
      VariantID   => $row->{variant_id},
      VariantName => $row->{variant_name},
      MRP         => $row->{MRP},
      SellPrice   => $row->{SellPrice},
   };
}

my $data_json = to_json(\@data);
```

It's a little extra work than option 2, but it has the smallest client-side memory footprint (if you didn't have to keep everything in memory).

Comment: My code for option 2 and 3 assumes every product you're interested in has at least one variant. If not, use `LEFT JOIN`s and avoid creating a variant if `$row->{variant_id}` isn't defined.